# Measuring and connecting a parallel LC circuit

Tags: antenna, passive-networks, vna

I have built an LC circuit at 3.4 MHz and measured it's resonance with a VNA as schown in this picture and described [here](https://www.nonstopsystems.com/radio/frank_radio_coax-sw.htm):

[image]

The parallel LC circuit is connected to the output of the VNA and is open, there is no ground connected.

Why do I not have to connect it to ground?

If I do so, the resonance disappears completely.

My goal is to use this as an antenna. The coil is a Helmholz pair and I want an oscillating magnetic field at the resonance in between the coils.

If I connect the circuit to an AC-source, there won't be  any current flowing since there is no ground connected, right?

I'm quite a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interest seems to be in generating oscillating magnetic fields, which suggests that you wish to maximize *current* at resonance.
A **series LC circuit** would be more appropriate, where resistance to current flow is minimum at resonance. Coil losses due to radiation, and losses due to its wire skin resistance are lumped together and shown as *inductor losses*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN5dXR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your VNA measurement tool likely excites the resonator with too-feeble a signal. The measurement setup most similar to the above excitation method would be:[image: series LC measurement]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
You are correct, I want to maximize the B-field, so the current, at resonance. I figured The parallel circuit would be more suitable since the current in the LC-circuit is maximized (infinite) at resonance?
Sinze the impedance is zero for the series circuit, is this the more optimal configuration in case of a driven system?
Thanks again!

Comment: Chances are good that your final driver wants to see a load around 50 ohms. A matching network to transform a series-LC load to 50 ohms is likely easier and lower-loss than a matching network to a parallel-LC load.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why do I not have to connect it to ground?*

You **do** need to connect both ends of the parallel tuned circuit to the VNA to analyse it. With no return connection (as shown in your diagram) you may still detect some form of resonance due to parasitic ground connections but, the measured Q of the circuit will not be representative of reality.

> *If I do so, the resonance disappears completely*

Then maybe you have connected it incorrectly or, due to the loading of the VNA's drive signal, the Q has dropped considerably and, although you think there may be no resonance, there is a shallow resonance you have not spotted yet.

> *The coil is a Helmholz pair and I want an oscillating magnetic field
> at the resonance in between the coils.*

That is not represented in your picture (just saying).

> *If I connect the circuit to an AC-source, there won't be any current
> flowing since there is no ground connected, right?*

Parasitic capacitance will cause small currents to flow but you won't get a significant magnetic field if that is your main aim.